# dd: warning: partial read (512 bytes); suggest iflag=fullblock

Tags: 14.04, sound, octave

Im trying to record and audio from octave and keep getting this warning and only get partial recordings..(partial read from pipe) I suppose.. IM running Ubuntu 14.04 on a sony vaio

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full command and error, I can only guess that you need to add iflag=fullblock and increase the buffer size. [Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html#dd-invocation) is a good overview of some of the options for dd.

Comment: its getting called from an octave function. IS there a way to globally set this "iflag"? Tanks